# Are any other Jewish prophecies extant beyond those in Tanach?

Tags: jewish-books, nevua-prophecy

When Klal Yisrael had access to prophecy, there were many thousands of people who achieved prophecy, but we are taught that only those whose prophecies were applicable throughout all generations had their messages canonized into Tana"ch. (Megillah 14a)

Did any of the other prophets of those times transcribe their prophecies as well - and if so, are any of those extant today? Surely these were people who achieved a high level of awareness and connection, I would imagine that reading about whatever they experienced would be a window into understanding the nature of prophecy and where we've come from.

Comment: You may want to check out the [tag:apocrypha]

Comment: How would we know these prophecies we're authentic if we find any?

Comment: How do we know that anything not canonized into the tanach was not discarded by the Anshei Knesses Hagedolah?

Comment: Suppose one would have a documented tradition. If such a thing is claimed to exist, we can discuss how to authenticate it. // Even if we were to assume that they were discarded by the Anshei Knesses HaGedola, would we not still be interested in reading about it? Don't many people read historical writings from across human history, especially related to the development of Yisrael?

Comment: Yes there were other prophets like abraham abulafia, Chaim vital, nachman Katofa to name just a few. they wrote about their prophecies and how to attain them. The study and attainment of prophecy was common among the kabbalists and Hasidei Ashkenaz. And even Tosfos mentions a few of them (like Ezra Hanavi), but they unfortunately didn't write anything down. The jewish philosophers were also obsessed  with it (like ramabm) but it is not known if they ever attained it.

Comment: @Bach Nevua ended with Micah. What levels anyone after that reached could not have been nevuah. Using Ezra is not valid to this question.

Comment: "Nevua ended with Micah." Wrong! it was with Haggai and Malachi. "What levels anyone after that reached could not have been nevuah." This is not so simple. According to the rambam, R Hai gaon and some others, prophecy is attainable even nowadays, although in a lesser form. The fact that tons of kabbalists and Hasidim were considered prophets in their own time (Shmuel Hachasid, Sheshet beneveniste, R Yosef Tov-elem were called prophets) proves my point. It is also known that the Zohar  calls the disciples of the Rashbi "true prophets".

Comment: Didn't one of the Chabad Rebbes say that Germany has X number of princes and if they should all unite, it would bring destruction to the world?

Comment: There were many other books of prophecy in the time of the prophets, several are mentioned in the Tanach itself, such as the Chronicles of the Kings of Judah, the book of Natan Hanavi, book of Gad Hachozeh, etc. As for the gemara you mention, there are some - such as Rabbi Tanchum Hayerushalmi - that interpret it not to mean that only what was put in Tanach was written down, but also other books, as well. This is evidenced by what I just wrote, of other books that used to be extant mentioned in Tanach. And there's more evidence. Unfortunately, none of these are known to be extant.

Comment: There are some speculations, though. For example, Heschel speculated that a certain midrash is quoting from a book of prophecies by Eldad and Meidad. Rabbi Ahron Marcus believed that our Chronicles is based off of "the Chronicles of the Kings of Judah" and our Kings off of "the Chronicles of the Kings of Israel". It's also possible that some Dead Sea texts include citations from some of these lost books, but as we're not familiar with them, we can't recognize them to be such.